# Strange error in newcommand with bibtex and hyperref

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, color

I have a very weird issue with newcommand and bibtex, as I want some citations to be colored differently. I created a MWE below with the things I want to do. Basically, I have two commands citeRedColored and citeBlueColored which should make citations with their respective colors. The two commands have exactly the same definition. However, citeBlueColored works fine but citeRedColored always outputs an error

"TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \font@name ->"

I am really lost, as you can see the two functions are completely identical...

Thanks a lot for your help !

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor={green}} 

\newcommand{\citeRedColored}[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}\cite{‌#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=green}}
\newcommand{\citeBlueColored}[1]{\hypersetup{citecolor=blue}\cite{#1}\hypersetup{citecolor=green}}
\title{My file}
\author{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{paper1} was published later than \cite{paper2} 
\\ 
\citeRedColored{paper1} was published later than \citeRedColored{paper2} 
\\
\citeBlueColored{paper1} was published later than \citeBlueColored{paper2} 

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Here is the file references.bib:

```
@article{paper1,
    title = {WordNet: a lexical database for English},
    year = {1995},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Miller, George A.},
    doi = {10.1145/219717.219748},
    number = {11},
    month = {11},
    pages = {39--41},
    volume = {38},
    publisher = {ACM}
}

@article{paper2,
    title = {Real-time computer vision with OpenCV},
    year = {2012},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    author = {Pulli, Kari and Baksheev, Anatoly and Kornyakov, Kirill and Eruhimov, Victor},
    doi = {10.1145/2184319.2184337},
    number = {6},
    month = {6},
    pages = {61},
    volume = {55},
    publisher = {ACM}
}
```

Comment: Could you include your bibliography into this MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/107497)?  I don't suppose that the blue reference doesn't exist, but the red reference does?

Comment: I just included it! No it's not that simple sadly, the red and blue commands both try to cite the same reference...

Comment: you managed to add a zero width joiner (U+200C) before the #1 in the command.

Comment: Thanks for this, I would never have guessed, I rewrote the command from scratch and it is working now I will close the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition contains an invisible space: Actually it is like this:

```
 \cite{U+200C#1}
```

where U+200C is the zero width joiner and pdflatex chokes over this. At best delete the whole command and retype it.